# How to Center 2 Divs Side by Side

Tags: html, css, centering

I have 2 `<div>`s each with a `<h1>` and a `<button>`. I want them to be centered but with space in between. I have scoured the internet looking at countless StackOverflow questions, articles, and tutorials but none of them seem to be working, here is my code: https://jsfiddle.net/obznmdcr/16/

```css
button {
    text-align: center;
    height: 75px;
    width: 225px;
    font-size: 30px;
    border-radius: 40px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: none;
    position: relative;
    box-shadow: 0px 4px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    cursor: pointer;
}

.panel-left {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    border-radius: 10px;
    display: grid;
    place-items: center;
    float: left;
    padding: 0px 30px 30px 20px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.panel-left h2 {
    font-family: Helvetica;
    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    margin-left: auto;
}

.panel-right {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    border-radius: 10px;
    display: grid;
    place-items: center;
    float: left;
    right: 500px;
    padding: 10px 20px 30px 20px;
    margin-left: 18%;
    margin-right: auto;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.panel-right h2 {
    font-family: Helvetica;
    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom: 25px;
}

.btn-left {
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, #ff5e62, #ff9966);
}
.btn-left:hover {
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, #ff9966, #ff5e62);
}
.btn-left:active {
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, #d68359, #d36668);
}

.btn-right {
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, #ff9966, #ff5e62);
}
.btn-right:hover {
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, #ff5e62, #ff9966);
}
.btn-right:active {
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, #d36668, #d68359);
}
```

```html
<div class="panel-left">
  <h2>Title Left</h2>
  <button class="btn-left" id="btn" type="button" onclick="console.log('button pressed');">Button Left</button>
</div>
<div class="panel-right">
  <h2>Title Right</h2>
  <button class="btn-right" id="btn" type="button" onclick="console.log('button pressed');">Button Right</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Centered vertically or horizontally? Is it possible to illustrate the layout you want?

Comment: I want them both to be on the same line and have the same distance from their respective window wall

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question does not specify if the `divs` have to be centered vertically as well.

**For centering only horizontally :**

**HTML :**

Warp HTML code in a `div`, with class like `.container` here.

**CSS :**

Set `display` as `flex` for `container` class, and set its `justify-content` property to `space-evenly`.

Remove `margin-left` and `margin-right` from `.panel-right`.

```css
.container{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

button {
  text-align: center;
  height: 75px;
  width: 225px;
  font-size: 30px;
  border-radius: 40px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: none;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.panel-left {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-radius: 10px;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  float: left;
  padding: 0px 30px 30px 20px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.panel-left h2 {
  font-family: Helvetica;
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  margin-left: auto;
}

.panel-right {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-radius: 10px;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  float: left;
  right: 500px;
  padding: 10px 20px 30px 20px;
  /*margin-left: 18%;
  margin-right: auto;*/
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.panel-right h2 {
  font-family: Helvetica;
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 25px;
}

.btn-left {
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #ff5e62, #ff9966);
}

.btn-left:hover {
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #ff9966, #ff5e62);
}

.btn-left:active {
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #d68359, #d36668);
}

.btn-right {
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #ff9966, #ff5e62);
}

.btn-right:hover {
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #ff5e62, #ff9966);
}

.btn-right:active {
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #d36668, #d68359);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="panel-left">
    <h2>Title Left</h2>
    <button class="btn-left" id="btn" type="button" onclick="console.log('button pressed');">Button Left</button>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-right">
    <h2>Title Right</h2>
    <button class="btn-right" id="btn" type="button" onclick="console.log('button pressed');">Button Right</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

**For centering vertically as well :**

In case you want them to be centered vertically as well, set height of `html`, `body`, `.container` to `100%` (or any other dimension if you wish), and set `align-items` property to `center` in `container` class.

Comment: thank you! https://jsfiddle.net/ctabgd0z/2/

Answer (score 0):

You have `float: left;` in your CSS for the right panel which I have removed.

I also set margin-right and left for the left and right panels.

```css
button {
        text-align: center;
        height: 75px;
        width: 225px;
        font-size: 30px;
        border-radius: 40px;
        overflow: hidden;
        border: none;
        position: relative;
        box-shadow: 0px 4px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .panel-left {
    margin-right: 20px;
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
        border-radius: 10px;
        float: left;
        padding: 0px 30px 30px 20px;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }

    .panel-left h2 {
        font-family: Helvetica;
        text-align: center;
        padding-bottom: 5px;
        margin-left: auto;
    }

    .panel-right {
    margin-left: 20px;
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
        border-radius: 10px;
        display: grid;
        place-items: center;
        right: 500px;
        padding: 10px 20px 30px 20px;
        margin-left: 18%;
        margin-right: auto;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }

    .panel-right h2 {
        font-family: Helvetica;
        text-align: center;
        padding-bottom: 25px;
    }

    .btn-left {
        background: linear-gradient(90deg, #ff5e62, #ff9966);
    }
    .btn-left:hover {
        background: linear-gradient(90deg, #ff9966, #ff5e62);
    }
    .btn-left:active {
        background: linear-gradient(90deg, #d68359, #d36668);
    }

    .btn-right {
        background: linear-gradient(90deg, #ff9966, #ff5e62);
    }
    .btn-right:hover {
        background: linear-gradient(90deg, #ff5e62, #ff9966);
    }
    .btn-right:active {
        background: linear-gradient(90deg, #d36668, #d68359);
    }
```

```html
<div class="panel-left">
      <h2>Title Left</h2>
      <button class="btn-left" id="btn" type="button" onclick="console.log('button pressed');">Button Left</button>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-right">
      <h2>Title Right</h2>
      <button class="btn-right" id="btn" type="button" onclick="console.log('button pressed');">Button Right</button>
    </div>
```

Comment: doesnt produce expected result: https://jsfiddle.net/xko3m6ej/1/

Answer (score 0):

Put your button and `<h2>` into a div and use flex.

Try this:

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  // justify-content: space-evenly;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="panel-left">
    <h2>Title Left</h2>
    <button class="btn-left" id="btn" type="button" onclick="console.log('button 
        pressed');">Button Left</button>
  </div>
  <div class="spacer">
  </div>
  <div class="panel-right">
    <h2>Title Right</h2>
    <button class="btn-right" id="btn" type="button" onclick="console.log('button 
        pressed');">Button Right</button>
  </div>
</div>
```